# JQuery Ajax GET basics

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

me again - sorry - I am trying to "teach myself" with help here some basic Jquery Ajax so far so good, but .. no offence to people sometimes the answers are very specific to requests - great, but may not be as helpful to others as certainkly a quick google search can get complex.  I have got a lot, but it is the simple things that I get stuck on.  Try this. A simple .click event and get using JQuery Ajax. to show results of the ajaxed page in a div.

```
<a href="?abc=1"  id="idoflink">Try this link to get results</a>
<div id="testit"></div>
```

Then Jquery/Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#idoflink').click(function() {   

 var idoflinkvaliable = $("#idoflink");

    $.ajax({
    cache: false, type: "GET", url: "tryit.php", data: "test=" + idoflinkvaliable,
    complete: function(data){ $("#testit").html(data.responseText); }

    });

    return false;
});
});
```

I know it'is not right - it doesn't work I get [object Object] - so whicj bit is wrong, my guess is in defining the variable?.  I know this is only a simple example but as I said I am trying to self teach - know PHP backwards - and a lot of what I find on Google starts beyond this, so your answers may not just help me but hopefully many others to.  Thanks in adavance.

Comment: OK I guess I have not explained fully - can show results either post or get BUT what cannot do is get the <a href"?abc=1"> variable to pass / be set inside the JQuery .click function.  When I said basics, sorry I ment basics.  Hard coding such as "atanamir" is no problem, Jonathan Sampson's a bit advanced for this question (sorry but thanks and very grateful)  Literally how fo you get the abc=1 variable into the JQuery set up?

Comment: From within the `click` event: `$(this).attr("href");`

Answer (score 1):

Don't go through `$.ajax();` for something like this. It's over-complicated for the task at hand. Also, it appears you're expecting json from the looks of your callback. That being the case, I recommend you use `$.getJSON();` instead:

```
$("#myLink").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.getJSON("tryit.php", { 'test':$(this).attr("id") }, function(data){
    // do something with data
    $(data).each(function(){
      $("#testit").append(this);
    });
  });
});
```

Also, be sure you're sending properly-encoded JSON back from your PHP script:

```
$values = array("red","green","blue");
print json_encode($values);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$("#idoflink").attr("href")` will get `?abc=1` from your link. You can append it to the url like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#idoflink').click(function() {   

    var idoflinkvaliable = $("#idoflink");

    $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      type: "GET",
      url: "tryit.php" + $("#idoflink").attr("href"),
      success: function(data){
        $("#testit").html(data.responseText);
      }
    });

    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer assumes you're returning JSON-encoded data.  If you aren't (it looks like from your usage you're wanting to return raw HTML instead of JSON data):

You can look here: [JQuery AJAX Samples](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#examples).  But it looks like you're supposed to be using the success event instead of the complete event:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: "name=John&location=Boston",
  success: function(msg){
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.  Another thing to make is that your PHP script is returning the correct data as well.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var href = $("#idoflink").attr("href");
if (href.indexOf("?") == 0 ) {
     href = href.substring(1, href.length() - 1);
}
$.ajax({   
cache: false, type: "GET", url: "tryit.php", data: href,   
success: function(data){ $("#testit").html(data.responseText); }   

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks but I guess I am not explaining myself very well at all.  None of the answers work/explain **to me** stress **to me** how to do it.  There are 4 totally different answers to one basic question.

I had haped the question was quite simple - take a variable from an href i.e.  pass that variable through JQuery/ajax to another page and then return the results into a div on the original page.  In php it is simple i.e. `if(isset($_GET['nameofvariable']): // do this // endif;`

I have tried all the answers above with a simple `echo $_GET['nameofvariable'];` on the receiving page but none of them give me the right result - sorry.

Comment: This is not a forum, Russell. "Answer your own question" is not for addressing other people's answers, you do that in their comments.